# How do I change the color of the like button?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button, colors

I'm making something like a Twitter like button.

I want to change the icon button color.

When clicking the button, changing from gray to red was successful.

But I don't know how to change it from red to gray.

I am using javascript and vue.

```
<template>
  <div id="postbox">
    <div class="thumbnail-img" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + postItem.img + ')'}"></div>
    <div>
        <h4>{{postItem.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{ cutDescript }}</p>
        <div class="text-date">{{postItem.date}}</div>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer">
            <img class="profile-img" :src="postItem.profileImg"/>
            <span class="writer">by <span class="bold">{{postItem.writer}}</span></span>
            <b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
                    :variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"
                    v-on:click="greet('grid')"
            />
            <span class="good_num">{{postItem.good}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'postbox',
  props: {
      post: {
          type: Object,
          default: function () {
              return {
                  title: 'Undefined',
                  descript: 'This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.This is description.',
                  date: '----년 --월 --일',
                  profileImg: '../assets/logo.png',
                  writer: 'unknown',
                  good: 0,
                  img: '../assets/logo.png'
              }
          }
      }
  },
  data () {
    return {
        postItem: this.post,
        currentMode: this.mode
    }
  },
  computed: {
      cutDescript: function () {
          if (this.postItem && this.postItem.descript && this.postItem.descript.length >= 200) {
              return `${this.postItem.descript.slice(0, 197)}...`
          } else if (this.postItem && !this.postItem.descript) {
              return '본문이 비어있습니다.'
          }
          return this.postItem.descript
      }
  },
  methods: {
       greet: function (mode) {
           if (mode !== 'grid' && mode !== 'map') {
                mode = 'grid'
            }
            this.currentMode = mode
            this.$emit('current-mode', this.currentMode)
       }
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I make the button switch between gray and red?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code which mentions grey or red in your question?

Comment: Gray is the default setting. Red is 'danger'. 
`:variant="currentMode == 'grid' ? 'danger' : ''"`
The part of the first code changes the color.
That changes when I click, I get a grid from the function.
When grid, the color changes to red.
So I think it is possible to return from red to gray by using conditional statements.
but it doesn't work as i want Is there any good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use a boolean data instead, to switch like button state's between red and grey

```
<b-icon icon="heart-fill" class="gap_margin_5px_horizontal"
   :variant="isLiked ? 'danger' : ''"
   @click="isLiked = !isLiked"
/>

data () {
 return {
    isLiked: false
 }
}
```